# gcc warnings for div-by-zero with std::array

Tags: gcc

say:

```
int main()
{
    int nX = 1 % 0; // <-- warning: divisioin by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
}
```

but

```
template<int N> struct A
{
    std::array<int, N> m_Data;

    int &Next()
    {
        return m_Data[(1 + 0) % N];   // <-- no warnings for N == 0
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<0> a; // nothing happens
}
```

why gcc won't raise any warnings even I use ``-Wall" ? Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

> why gcc won't raise any warnings even I use "-Wall" ?

Simply because the behaviour of gcc (or rather, g++; g++5.2 in
my case) is inconsistent in this respect. It appears to forget
divide-by-zero diagnosis in a template-instantiating context. In the following program:

```
int foo(int i) {
    return i % 0;
}

template<typename T>
T bar(T i) {
    return i % 0;
}


#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << bar(1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the instantiation of the function template `bar<T>` that is caused by the
call `bar(1)` is a function identical to `foo`. However:

```
$ g++-5 -c -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int foo(int)’:
main.cpp:2:14: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
     return i % 0;
              ^
```

g++ diagnoses division by zero only in `foo`, whereas:

```
$ clang++-3.7 -c -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra main.cpp
main.cpp:2:14: warning: remainder by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    return i % 0;
             ^ ~
main.cpp:7:14: warning: remainder by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    return i % 0;
             ^ ~
main.cpp:16:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'bar<int>' requested here
    std::cout << bar(1) << std::endl;
```

clang++ diagnoses division by zero in both `foo` and `bar<int>`.

Similarly in the program:

```
#include <array>

template<int N> struct A
{
    std::array<int, N> m_Data;

    int &Next()
    {
        return m_Data[(1 + 0) % N];
    }
};

struct B
{
    std::array<int, 0> m_Data;

    int &Next()
    {
        return m_Data[(1 + 0) % 0];
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    A<0> a;
    std::cout << a.Next() << std::endl;
    B b;
    std::cout << b.Next() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

class `B` is identical to class `A<0>`, but g++ diagnoses only:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘int& B::Next()’:
main.cpp:32:31: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
         return m_Data[(1 + 0) % 0];
                               ^
```

whereas clang++ diagnoses:

```
main.cpp:32:31: warning: remainder by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
        return m_Data[(1 + 0) % 0];
                              ^ ~
main.cpp:22:31: warning: remainder by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
        return m_Data[(1 + 0) % N];
                              ^ ~
main.cpp:43:20: note: in instantiation of member function 'A<0>::Next' requested here
    std::cout << a.Next() << std::endl;
                   ^
```

Of course, a conforming compiler is not required to diagnose division by zero, 
even when it can. It's just being helpful if it does so, when it can.

It's unhelpful if it sometimes does so when it can and sometimes doesn't. However,
as you may already know, compiletime sanity-checks on the properties of
template parameters can be implemented with features of the language and library such
as [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert),
[`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and
[SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). Your
example template could require that `N` != 0 like:

```
template<int N> struct A
{
    static_assert(N != 0,"N cannnot be 0 in struct A<N>");
    std::array<int, N> m_Data;

    int &Next()
    {
        return m_Data[(1 + 0) % N];
    }
};
```

Comment: @user1490269 Welcome to Stackoverflow! Should you wish to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer you can do so by clicking on the green check-mark.